# String to Float in Objective-C for Map Kit

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit

I'm trying to pass some lat/long values from a JSON doc to iPhone's Map Kit to then plot the points on the map. The values are coming from an NSArray:

```
CGFloat goLat = [valfields objectForKey: @"geo_lat"];
CGFloat golong = [valfields objectForKey: @"geo_long"];


CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord = {golat, golong}; etc...
```

But I'm getting an "incompatible types" error.

My guess is I need to cast the string values from my array to CGFloat? But I'm just sure.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Casting' isn't what you need to do, but if your array (actually from your code it looks like a dictionary) contains strings, then yes, you need to convert them to a numeric format.  Give this a try:

```
CGFloat goLat = [[valfields objectForKey: @"geo_lat"] floatValue];
```

From the [NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/floatValue):

> ### floatValue
>
> Returns the floating-point value of the receiver’s text as a `float`.
>
> `- (float)floatValue`
>
> **Return Value** 
> The floating-point value of the receiver’s text as a `float`, skipping whitespace at the beginning of the string. Returns `HUGE_VAL` or `–HUGE_VAL` on overflow, `0.0` on underflow. Also returns `0.0` if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid text representation of a floating-point number.

In addition, `NSString` has a `-doubleValue` method.  There is also an `NSNumber` class, which might be a better representation than strings for your data.